# Rails subscribing from frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subscribe

I have a checkbox on a form on which would tell me whether the user wants to subscribe or not. I will take that variable as a boolean and run a method that would subscribe the user to a mailing list or unsubscribe if vice versa.

My question is what is the best method of doing this high-level?

With the subscribe/unsubscribe as methods of the user model, I cannot figure out the proper way to doing this. Where should my form submit to so that I can check the boolean value and run the proper method?

Comment: your form should post data to your users controller, where you will check the params and accordingly subscribe them or do whatever required.

Answer (score 0):

At form submit you will have submitted values as params in your controller. For example, if it's a checkbox your params[:email_subscription] could be 1 or 0.

Then in the controller you will write the logic, e.g.

```
if params[:email_subscription] == 1
     user.subscribe(true)
elsif params[:email_subscription] == 0
     user.subscribe(false)
end
```

Then in your User model you need the "real" logic based on the true/false variable you passed, e.g.:

```
def subscribe(var)
   [update user subscription based on var being true or false]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send ajax request to users_controller, or submit your form to it.

```
var url = '/users/:id/subscribe' 
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  data: { channel_ids: ["1", "2"] }, 
  success: function() {
    alert('Sucess Subscribe')
  }
});
```

Make action `subscribe` in users_controller, or use `update` action as the following.

```
def subscribe
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.channels = paramas[:user][:channel_ids]
  @user.save
end
```

And you can use **koudoku gem** to subscription, read more about [koudoku gem](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku)